Is there a way to vertically align the column header / title text in Tabulator?
I have applied text wrapping and horizontal alignment to the column titles within the header row of my Tabulator table and now I need to vertically align the titles.  Asked differently, is there an attribute comparable to the Tabulator headerHozAlign attribute for use in vertically aligning the column title(s)?
For reference, the following CSS is utilized to accomplish: (a) text wrapping of the header row; and (b) height adjustment of the header row:
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .tabulator-col-content .tabulator-col-title {
    white-space: normal !important;
}

.tabulator-col-title {
    height: 2rem;
}

Similarly, the headerHozAlign parameter has been defined for each column, as follows:
headerHozAlign: "center"

The following image illustrates what the header row looks like now:

The following image illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Try removing .tabulator-col-title { height: 2rem; } and adding .tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col { justify-content: flex-end !important; } instead.

Thanks for the assistance.  I actually wound up with a combination of my original attempt and your suggestion, as follows:  .tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {             height: 3rem;             justify-content: flex-end !important;         }   It works perfectly!!!
